# How to add NOT NULL constraint as composite in MySQL ?

Tags: mysql, constraints, multiple-columns, composite, notnull

I want to add NOT NULL constraint for some multiple columns. Individually those columns can be NULL. But altogether there should there should be some data. Is it possible with MySQL?

Comment: This is not possible to do in MySQL with constraints.  You can do this with a trigger or in most other databases using a check constraint.

Comment: It is quite possible that your design is bad. Eg radio-button FK columns are an anti-pattern for database/SQL subtyping/polymorphism.

Comment: @philipxy Thank you very much. Can you please explain how to add check boxes selection into the database ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the guidance. Im new in this. Will refer about triggers and other databases.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Please use more words. My last comment says maybe it is a bad idea to have your radio-button design. But that depends on what you are using it for, ie what the business/application you are modeling is. Are your columns FKs? Did you research the keywords I gave you? You can read questions about those things and also about having only one of many FKs be non-null. You can describe your business/application and your design for it & in another question *if following a design textbook & a lot of googling of different question phrasings is no help*. (Unlikely.)